# Use collection->get() instead of collection->pluck()

Tags: php, laravel, methods, collections, laravel-5

I am using [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) for managing roles and displaying content. Per the docs you can retrieve a users roles by using `$roles = $user->roles()->pluck('name')`. My problem is that the data returned is `["admin"]` rather than just `admin`. I was reviewing the collections methods and it looked like `get('name')` would return what I was looking for. When I try to use the following command `Auth::user()->roles()->get('name')` I get

```
1/1
ErrorException in BelongsToMany.php line 360:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::getSelectColumns() must be of the type array, string given
```

It seems to me like the `get()` method is expecting an array however, I'm trying to reference an item in the array. The raw output of `Auth::user()->roles()->get()` is `[{"id":1,"name":"admin","created_at":"2016-03-10 06:24:47","updated_at":"2016-03-10 06:24:47","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]`

I have found a workaround for pulling the correct content, but it is using regex for removing the unwanted characters that are included in the `pluck()` method.

```
preg_replace('/\W/i','', Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('name'))
```

It seems like I'm missing something or approaching using the `get()` method incorrectly. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `pluck()` will return the value of the given column *for each model in the collection*, which would explain the array. In your case it looks like the user has only one role, so you get an array with only one item. If the user had multiple roles, you would likely get an array with multiple items in it.

On the other hand, the `get()` method is used to execute a query against the database after a query is built. The results of the query are what is returned. To return a collection of models with only a single value you will need to pass an array with just the one column you want, but that will just select models, which does not appear to be what you ultimately need.

You can try this instead: `$roles = $user->roles()->first()->name`

The call to first() will grab the first model in the collection returned by `roles()`, and then you can grab the name of the role from that model.

I typically throw some error checking around this:

```
$role = $user->roles()->first();

if (is_null($role)) {
    //Handle what happens if no role comes back
}

$role_name = $role->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because an user can have many roles, so roles is a collection.
If you are **100% sure** that a user will have only one role, you can easily do

`Auth::user()->roles()->first()->name`

That will get the first item of that collection (the role) and then its name.